# How do i copy the boot.img without rooting phone?

Tags: adb, root-access, boot

I want to get the  boot.img of my android phone (mobile/model doesnt matter i want a general one) without rooting the phone. I have ADB installed and using a linux machine in which i can communicate to phone via ADB. Can any one help ? remember i dont want to root my phone i just want to get the boot img.

Comment: Taking a dump of boot partition means taking a dump of a block device and from security consideration I don't think you would be able to do it without root access, as long as you're running Android. However, depending upon the device you may try different offline techniques. E.g. for most of the Mediatek devices, you may try "MTK droid root tools" to take boot dump. On the other hand, you may use a custom Recovery to take boot backup but I assume you're worried of warranty and not rooting so custom recovery would be no go here.